# IIS killing ASPNET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis-8

I'm hosting an ASPNET Core 1.1 app on IIS with the following settings to keep it always running

[image]

However, I see the app getting terminated time to time. Before termination I see the following in the logs

```
2018-03-14 17:20:53.202 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:32751/myapp/iisintegration  0
2018-03-14 17:20:53.205 [Information] Request finished in 3.98ms 202 
2018-03-14 17:20:53.203 [Error] Unhandled exception
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

The `POST /iisintegration` looks interesting. Is IIS sending a command to terminate the app?

**P.S.**

After digging around [IIS integration middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration), it looks like that `POST` is actually IIS sending a termination command. This is the code that handles it

```
private static readonly PathString ANCMRequestPath = new PathString("/iisintegration");
...
    // Handle shutdown from ANCM
if (HttpMethods.IsPost(httpContext.Request.Method) &&
    httpContext.Request.Path.Equals(ANCMRequestPath) &&
    string.Equals(ANCMShutdownEventHeaderValue, httpContext.Request.Headers[MSAspNetCoreEvent], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // Execute shutdown task on background thread without waiting for completion
    var shutdownTask = Task.Run(() => _applicationLifetime.StopApplication());
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status202Accepted;
    return;
}
```

**So my question is: Is there a way to disable this functionality?**

Comment: Just remove the complete IF block could help?! Or comment the line `var shutdownTask ...` if the rest of the block is important for something.

Comment: Lol.. if aspnet team allows me to do that just to fix my issue ;)

Comment: Does your app run without IIS integration?

Comment: Do you have a file called "app_offline.html" in your root directory? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module#appofflinehtm
Maybe that is causing the shutdown?

Comment: Unhandled exceptions from a thread can terminate the whole process.

Comment: @Brad yes it runs without IIS integration. The termination is initiated by IIS. I'm trying to find a way to disable it

Comment: @ubi were you lucky with this matter? I have the same problem

Comment: No luck so far, what I ended up doing was to create a shell script to ping the application periodically. yuck, I know. There's another option which I haven't tried which is setting the Recycling time interval in application pool to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove your `Recycling Conditions` from your application pool